# Implementing notifications with Django Rest Framework jwt authentication

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework, android-notifications, django-rest-framework-jwt

I have developed an android app which uses Django rest framework as backend with JWT Authentication.

Now I want to add notification service to it. There are many notification service providers like firebase cloud message and azure notification centre.

I need some guidance to implement this

Like, this is my user profile model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default= False)
```

and **I only want to send a notification to the users who are logged in as teacher**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For notifications in my app i was using Firebase. There is [realy nice library](https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django) for connecting it to django.
If you wanna send notifications only to teachers, you can do it in bulk like in [this example](https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django#sending-messages-in-bulk):

```
from fcm_django.models import FCMDevice

devices = FCMDevice.objects.all()

devices.send_message(title="Title", body="Message")
devices.send_message(title="Title", body="Message", data={"test": "test"})
devices.send_message(data={"test": "test"})
```

Just change `FCMDevice.objects.all()` to set of devices connected to teachers.

Comment: This is the package I need. Is there any docs or tutorials on how to register a device and store the registration ID with user id.

Comment: Show I creat a serialise class with post req for storing devide reg id? Like I should store the send a post ret to this at the lime of login success?

Comment: You don't have to create anythink. If you add `fcm_django` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` you will see in admin panel that model for devices is already added. If you wanna register device and add it to user, you can use [FCMDeviceAuthorizedViewSet](https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django#django-rest-framework-drf-support). Becouse you have to be authorized, user id will be automaticlly  set for device.

Comment: I think I should use FCMDeviceViewSet as I am using jwt not the rest Framework Authorization.

Comment: Not necessary, I'm using jwt as well, with `djangorestframework_simplejwt` and it works just fine.